# How to create and modify jar files with an easy GUI tool?

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

for example we have a jar file that use two library and these library's paths placed in class path in manifest, and we want to add new library to it path. at first i think editing manifest file as a text file and replace it is enough, but it's not the solution (!). i need a gui tool to do this task just work

Answer (score 3):

Some of the GUI tools are IZArc or 7zip.

Comment: IZArc doesn't have the collision (case) problems that 7zip seems to have (e.g. `This.class` and `this.class` are not seen as the same files).

Answer (score 2):

jar files are simply zip archives (with optional manifest added). You can use any zip manager e.g. [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Comment: for example we have a jar file that use two library and these library's paths placed in class path in manifest, and we want to add new library to it path. at first i think editing manifest file as a text file and replace it is enough, but it's not the solution (!). i need a gui tool to do this task just work

Comment: 7zip seems to fail when jars contained mixed case collisions. The file "this.class" and "This.class" are not the same (in Java) but 7zip thinks they are and reports errors.